# Enums and With in Kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin

Either my syntax is wrong, or you can't use `with` to apply to `enum` constants.  IntelliJ says it's because `RegexOption` doesn't have a companion object, and that `RegexOption needs to be initialized here`.  I didn't think you could instantiate an enum.

```
// this works:
val RX_OPTIONS = mapOf(
  'c' to RegexOption.COMMENTS,
  'd' to RegexOption.DOT_MATCHES_ALL,
  'e' to RegexOption.CANON_EQ,
  'i' to RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE,
  'l' to RegexOption.LITERAL,
  'm' to RegexOption.MULTILINE,
  'u' to RegexOption.UNIX_LINES
)

// this doesn't work:
val RX_OPTIONS2 = with(RegexOption) { mapOf(
  'c' to COMMENTS,
  'd' to DOT_MATCHES_ALL,
  'e' to CANON_EQ,
  'i' to IGNORE_CASE,
  'l' to LITERAL,
  'm' to MULTILINE,
  'u' to UNIX_LINES
) }
```

Why doesn't the second example work?  If they're not in the companion object, it doesn't seem like they'd be in an instance.  Does `with` have a counterpart that could work in this situation?  If not, is it easy to write one (since `with` is just a [one-liner](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L43))?

***EDIT (Refining the question):***

In a block (not necessarily even this one) where I'm typing 20 references to the same long enum names like **`Class.Inner.VeryInner.YouGetTheIdea.SOMEOPTION`** is it possible to factor out all but the `SOMEOPTION` name using a with-statement-like construct *just* for a block -- even one that I must write myself as a higher order function?  I've considered `typealias`, but I really want this to apply only to the block.  **The answer below tells me the `with` higher-order function doesn't work for this, but is there a way to do it?**

Comment: I removed the misleading tag "with-statement". In kotlin it is not a statement but a higher order function.

Comment: It might have helped people find this question who (like me) were under the mistaken impression that Kotlin *has* a `with` statement, especially because search engines often de-prioritize prepositions like "with".  Fine with the edit though.

Answer (score 5):

The one-liner implementation of `with` is:

```
public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R = receiver.block()
```

The `T.()` is a **function literal with a receiver**, and the receiver is an object. You're passing a class.

The documentation for Kotlin **function literals with receiver** can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html).

Comment: Thanks -- with the mention of the companion class (reminiscent but not he same as Java static members), I figured it would work because the constants were members.  Is IGNORE_CASE within an enum more like a nested class than a property?  I'm guessing then you're saying it's not possible to do what I'm trying to do, because there's no language construct that would even allow me to write it?

Comment: @sirksel I think you're looking for the [`when` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) or you could just use the map and its `get` operator...

Comment: While this is helpful, I'm still looking for a **general solution** , and not necessarily just for this mapping application.  Maybe `when` is the answer, but I'm not really interested in switching functionality, just name shortening for a block.  If you're envisioning a way I could use `when` for that, could you propose a separate answer with a quick code example?  See the **edit** portion of my question above.